# Can't restart MySQL, Start request repeated too quickly

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, systemctl

I can't restart my MySQL server with `systemctl` or any other ways.
On `journalectl` it says

```
mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

Here the output screenshot
[image]

Comment: Check MySQL's own log.

Comment: MySQL logs are usually in /var/log/mysql.